# matlab codegen linking/embedding mex

Tags: matlab, matlab-coder

Ok so I developed a code in MATLAB with numerous nested loops that cannot be vectorized.
To speed up processing I "codegen" this file. The problem here is that I am calling a function which is in gcc (or mex) and not in a .m file. Function here: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/21702-3d-volume-interpolation-with-ba-interp3--fast-interp3-replacement

Does anyone knows how to fix this?

Here goes the structure of the main file (main.m):

```
function OUT=main(IN)
assert(isa(IN,'double'));
assert(all(size(IN)==[256,256,128]));

for i=1:I
for j=1:J
for m=1:M
[.....]

OUT=ba_interp3(Y,X,Z,IN,reg_y,reg_x,reg_z,'nearest'); %%% function in either cpp or mex file

[.....]

end
end
end
end
```

MATLAB ERROR:

```
Only MATLAB files are supported for code generation. Unsupported file extension 'mexa64'
```

Comment: Where does that function come from? It doesn't look like it is part of the standard NATLAB (and toolboxes) installation.

Comment: @am304 Yes it is not. it is a fast implementation of interp3. Further, interp3 cannot be fully converted to C-like code so the need of this function.

Comment: You need to get the *.m version of this file then, and the code gen process should work.

Comment: @am304 I cannot get the m version because it does not exist. it is in c code. Nonetheless, it seems that by providing the header of the function in a .m file with the same name and adding the coder.extrinsic('ba_interp3'); in the main file solves the problem. Thanks for the help

Comment: OK, glad you found a solution